# Javascript / jQuery - search for a numbered class and jump to nearest number if class not found

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a list, which represents *some* hours of a day. Like so:

```
<ol>
    <li class="9">Item</li>
    <li class="10">Item</li>
    <li class="11">Item</li>
    <li class="13">Item</li>
    <!-- and so on .... -->
</ol>
```

And I have a "Now" button which gets the current hour and then animates to find that hour in the list, like this:

```
$('#jump-to-now').click(function () {
        // new date object
    var date = new Date(),
        // give us the hour
        theHour = date.getHours();

    scrollToHour(theHour);
});

function scrollToHour(hourAsNumber) {
    // use the hour number and match it against a day with a class of that number
    var theListingItem = listingDays.filter('.active-day').find('li').filter('.' + hourAsNumber),
        // get the offset relative to the document
        offsetTop = theListingItem.offset().top;

    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: offsetTop
    }, slideAnimationTime);
}
```

The only problem here is that if there is no list item with a class of that hour, nothing happens. What I'd like to do, is go to the nearest hour *after* the current hour.

For example, it's 7am and the user clicks the button, the code finds that the nearest listing item match *after 7am* is 9am and it jumps to that list item.

How can I do this?

Comment: "In CSS2, identifiers (including element names, classes, and IDs in selectors) can contain only the characters [A-Za-z0-9] and ISO 10646 characters 161 and higher, plus the hyphen (-); they cannot start with a hyphen or a digit. They can also contain escaped characters and any ISO 10646 character as a numeric code (see next item). For instance, the identifier “B&W?” may be written as “B\&W\?” or “B\26 W\3F”." - Classes should not begin with a digit.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out David, I didn't know that. Is it the same for CSS3? And does it also apply to ID's?

Comment: @Owen you can use a different attribute maybe called Hours and give that a value, than search by attribute like :
$("[Hours='"+hourAsNumber+"']");

Comment: "identifiers (including element names, classes, and IDs in selectors)" - Yes it applies to ID's. I would imagine it is the same for CSS3, as it has been like this throughout CSS. Firefox used to ignore classes beginning with a digit (It might still do).

Comment: You should really use the data-* attribute, such as `data-hour="5"` ... It'd be a lot more semantic, using classes for data is poor design in a lot of persons eyes.

Comment: Can you show your full DOM Structure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The logic, roughly (you may need to tweak):

```
function scrollToHour(hourAsNumber) {

    var lis = listingDays.filter('.active-day').find('li');

    // use the hour number and match it against a day with a class of that number
    var theListingItem = lis.filter('.' + hourAsNumber);

    // if no item for the specified hour, find nearest
    if(theListingItem.length == 0) {
        var delta = 1;

        while(theListingItem.length == 0 && delta <= lis.length) {
            // check next
            theListingItem = lis.filter('.' + (hourAsNumber + delta) );

            // check previous (uncomment if needed)
            /*
            if(theListingItem.length == 0) {
                theListingItem = lis.filter('.' + (hourAsNumber - delta) );
            }
            */

            delta++;
        }
    }

    // get the offset relative to the document
    var offsetTop = theListingItem.offset().top;

    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: offsetTop
    }, slideAnimationTime);
}
```

Comment: if user have both an item with class 10 and 15 and the current hour is 11, the loop will find the first element (11), but he wants to find the first element *after* the current hour (15). And imho, calling several times filter() in a loop doesn't look really efficient to me :)

Comment: @FabrizioCalderan - The question mentions "nearest", not "nearest next". If "nearest next" is what is needed, removing the `if` inside the `while` loop will suffice.

Comment: The question states: *What I'd like to do, is go to the nearest hour **after** the current hour.*

Comment: @FabrizioCalderan - You're right. I missed the italicized *after* in the body part of the question! Have commented out that part in the answer. OP can uncomment it if needed.

Comment: ok, as last suggestion you should be careful about the infinite loop you're creating if current hour is `14` and the last available element has class `13`

Comment: yes, an end condition must be specified (maybe something like `numItewration >= total number of li's`). This is just the rough logic.

Comment: @Techfoobar, can you edit your answer to prevent the infinite loop?

Comment: @Owen - Updated. The `&& delta <= lis.length` in the while condition will ensure that the total number of tries does not exceed the total number of li's available.

Answer (score 1):

Premising that a class should not start with a number, this is an example jsbin with *valid* classname : http://jsbin.com/ibeteb/3/edit

```
<ol>
    <li class="h9">Item</li>
    <li class="h10">Item</li>
    <li class="h14">Item</li>
    <li class="h19">Item</li>
    <!-- and so on .... -->
</ol>
```

---

```
var hourAsNumber = 12;
var theListingItem = $('ol li').filter(function(i, el) {
  var h = +($(el).attr('class').substring(1));
  if (h >= hourAsNumber) return $(el);
})[0];


console.log(theListingItem); // jump to this element (li.h14 in the example)
```

---

Note that `theListingItem` will be `undefined` when there's no item available (e.g. when in the example `hourAsNumber = 20`).

So before checking the `offset()` and starting the scroll, be sure that the element exists, e.g.

```
if (theListingItem.length) {
   /* an available hour was found - here you scroll */
}
else {
   /* say the user "you arrived too late. try again tomorrow" :)
    * or do nothing 
    */
}
```

Comment: +1, Thanks Fabrizio, the other answer sits a little more in line with what I'm doing. Also, thanks for your comments on the other answer.

Comment: @Owen. only be care that the condition chosen in the accepted answer (the length of <li> items) is not reliable. What if you have *only* 2 <li> with class `9, 14`, and your current hour is `10`? The search will end too early before finding the element `14`

Answer (score 1):

you should not start a class name with a number. change your class like

```
<ol>
    <li class="h9">Item</li>
    <li class="h10">Item</li>
    <li class="h11">Item</li>
    <li class="h13">Item</li>
    <!-- and so on .... -->
</ol>
```

Then you can try this

```
function scrollToHour(hourAsNumber) {   
    var hours = listingDays.filter('.active-day').find('li');
    var theListingItem = hours.filter('.h' + hourAsNumber);

    while(!theListingItem.get(0))
    {
      if(hourAsNumber<=24)
         theListingItem = hours.filter('.h' + (++hourAsNumber));
     }
     // get the offset relative to the document
     var offsetTop = theListingItem.offset().top;

     $('html, body').animate({
         scrollTop: offsetTop
     }, slideAnimationTime);
}
```